# Guardar 2 colecciones de laravel, en 1 solo

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

estoy algo confuso con un tema, tengo 2 datos recibidos de una consulta de laravel.

```
$groups = Group::join('user_group', 'user_group.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_group.user_id')
        ->where('users.id', \Auth::id())
        ->orderBy('user_group.created_at', 'desc')
        ->select('groups.*')
        ->get();
```

Esto me devuelve algo como esto.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1636
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Group {#1635
      #dates: array:2 [
        0 => "deleted_at"
        1 => "deleted_at"
      ]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "groups"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [
        "id" => "6d084b84-2597-4ea8-934b-9d87a66b69f5"
        "name_group" => "aaav"
        "avatar" => "group/avatar/6d084b84-2597-4ea8-934b-9d87a66b69f5"
        "created_at" => "2020-10-21 23:53:16"
        "updated_at" => "2020-10-21 23:53:16"
        "deleted_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:6 [
        "id" => "6d084b84-2597-4ea8-934b-9d87a66b69f5"
        "name_group" => "aaav"
        "avatar" => "group/avatar/6d084b84-2597-4ea8-934b-9d87a66b69f5"
        "created_at" => "2020-10-21 23:53:16"
        "updated_at" => "2020-10-21 23:53:16"
        "deleted_at" => null
      ]
```

En caso de que tenga 2 devoluciones con el mismo valor, y mismo tamaño de columna y mas, como podría unirlas.

He intentado lo siguiente

```
 $collection = array();
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        array_push($collection, [
            'id' => $group ->id,
            'name_group' => $group ->name_group,
            'avatar' => $group ->avatar,
            'created_at' => $group ->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $group ->updated_at,
        ]);
    }
    $otro = collect($collection);
    foreach ($otro as $group) {
        dd($group->id);
    }
```

Llenar un arreglo y  luego pasarlo a collection. Pero no me deja llamarlo como `$group->id`, sino como `$group['id']`, no deseo eso, es más una duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final el problema que tenia era que para leerlo `$group->id` de esta manera tenia que convertirlo en Objeto, de ahí todo se hizo mas fácil para lo que tenia pensado.

Lo hice de la siguiente manera, por si alguien le puede ser de utilidad.

```
$collection = json_decode(json_encode($collection), FALSE);
```

Tome como referencia la siguiente respuesta del SO English.

[How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)